# Decompressing a .zip file

Tags: powershell, 7zip

```
PARAM (  
    [string] $SourceZipPath, #= "X:\Somepath\Full\Of\Zipfiles",  
    [string] $DestinationPath #= "X:\Somepath\to\extract\to"
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $SourceZipPath -Recurse | % {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x" $_.fullname "-o" $DestinationPath} -Include *.ZIP
```

Please suggest the correction in the above code when I am trying to run it gives the following error:

```
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "-Include" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".  


At C:\Users\******\Desktop\Zip****Extractor-v0.6.ps1:11 char:53  
-Recurse | % {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x" "-o" $Destinatio ...  
+ CategoryInfo:InvalidArgument:(:)[ForEach-Object], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Comment: `-Include *.ZIP` should be before the pipe, ie `Get-Childitem $SourceZipPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP |`

Answer (score 0):

As [4c74356b41 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969078/power-shell-decompressing-the-zip-file/40969901#comment69147144_40969078), you have to put the `-Include` parameter to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet:

```
Param
(  
    [string] $SourceZipPath, #= "X:\Somepath\Full\Of\Zipfiles",  
    [string] $DestinationPath #= "X:\Somepath\to\extract\to"
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $SourceZipPath -Include *.ZIP -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object {
        & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x" $_.fullname "-o" $DestinationPath
    }
```

Comment: thanku for this help but it was showing                                         Command Line Error:
Too short switch:
-o

Comment: @ShivaGupta There has to be no space between the -o and the folder.